# c++ using memcpy to copy inside the array

Tags: c++, memcpy

If I have an array of elements, is it okay to use memcpy to copy some data from the back of an array to the front part

Presented in code:

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

memcpy(a, a + 2, 3 * sizeof(int));
```

As you can see some parts are copied to the other place in the front and then overwritten later (number 3).

Array after memcpy is {3, 4, 5, 4, 5}, but does this invoke undefined behaviour or is it completely valid to do such thing? I'm using c++ and VS2017 compiler.

Comment: That's what [`memove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) is for.

Comment: »If the objects overlap the behavior is undefined.« http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy

Comment: `man memcpy` : *"The memory areas must not overlap."*

Comment: thank you henri menke, u can post it as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Use `std::copy`.

Comment: @Pete Using `std::copy` for that is as undefined as using `memcpy`.

Comment: @zett42 -- no, it's not. The constraint is that the destination iterator must not be in the source range.

Comment: @zett42 Nope, [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) is appropriate when copying overlapping ranges "to the left". There's also [`std::copy_backward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) when going the other direction.

Comment: @Pete I see... in my mind source and destination of `memcpy` were swapped. Always confusing that destination is first parameter.

Comment: @zett42 -- yeah, C functions tend to look like assignment: the destination first, then the source. C++ functions are backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ok: `memcpy` requires that the source and destination regions not overlap. C specifically provides the function `memmove` for cases where the regions *do* overlap.

Since you're tagged C++ here, you could also consider using `std::copy` as its constraint is weaker than `memcpy`: Just the the destination iterator must be outside the range to be copied, which is the case in your scenario.